# Why are these curly braces necessary in sed?

Tags: sed

I wanted to do a range limited search in sed so I tried

```
sed -n '195,210 /add/ p' <file>
```

Which gave

> sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unknown command: `/'

Purely as a guess, I tried adding curly braces:

```
sed -n '195,210{/add/p}' <file>
```

And it was successful, but Im trying to understand *why* it worked with the braces were added.
I kind of get, that in bash, braces can delimit an expression (and possibly increase its order of execution), but in the case of sed what are these braces doing?

Relevant info

```
$ sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2

$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.11
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Per the [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799) standard's [page on `sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html):

> The script shall consist of editing commands of the following form:
>
> ```
> [address[,address]]function
> ```
>
> where *`function`* represents a single-character command verb from the list in 
>   [Editing Commands in sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_03), followed by any applicable arguments.

So the first non-blank character after the address is taken as a command verb - in your particular case it's `/` hence the error: `char 9: unknown command: '/'`.
The braces are referenced further down:

> ```
> [2addr] {editing command
> editing command
> ...
> }
> ```
>
>   Execute a list of `sed` editing commands only when the pattern space is selected.  …

<sup>[*2addr*] is an indicator that the maximum number of permissible addresses is two.</sup>

To clarify a point made above, the **Addresses** section of [`sed(1)`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed) says:

> `Sed` commands can be given with no addresses,
>   in which case the command will be executed for all input lines;
>   with one address, in which case the command will be executed only
>   for input lines which match that address;
>   or with two addresses, in which case the command will be executed
>   for all input lines which match the inclusive range of lines
>   starting from the first address and continuing to the second address. 
>   Three things to note about address ranges:
>   the syntax is *addr1*,*addr2* (i.e., the addresses are separated by a comma);
>           … *(and other stuff not relevant to this discussion)* …

The [gnu info page (`info sed`)](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/sed-3.02/html_node/sed_7.html) has a similar description of `{` and `}`,
under "3.4 Often-Used Commands":

> ```
> { COMMANDS }
> ```
>
>   A group of commands may be enclosed
>     between
>   `{`
>   and
>   `}`
>   characters.
>     This is particularly useful when you want a group of commands to be triggered
>     by a single address (or address-range) match.

Otherwise said, braces are used to apply multiple commands at the same address or to nest addresses.
The standard isn't very explicit here<sup>1</sup> but the left brace `{` *is actually* a command that starts a group of other sed commands (the group ends with a right brace `}`).

And, at the risk of really going **TL;DR**, the issue is
that `195`, `210`, and `/add/` are all *addresses*. 
No `sed` commands can be invoked with three addresses. 
So the way to make your command work
is to invoke the `{` command on the address range `195,210`,
and then (within that range) invoke the `p` command on the address `/add/`.

---

1:
though if you read the entire page it is mentioned that:
*Command verbs other than **{**, **a**, **b**, **c**, **i**, **r**, **t**, **w**, **:**, and **#** can be followed by...*

Comment: excellent, thanks. This was the only answer that addressed the fact that other "groups of multiple commands" dont require braces e.g. `sed -n '195,210s/old/new/p' <file>` works fine. Links to POSIX standard also useful.

Comment: @user4668401 - note that `195,210s/old/new/p` is actually a range followed by _a single_ command: `s`;  in this case `p` is not a command, it is a flag (it means print _if_ a replacement was made) see the manual for `s` syntax: `s/regexp/replacement/flags`. That's why it works without braces...

Comment: ah right. So in the case of this command: `sed -n '195,210{/add/p}' <file>`, there are 2 commands, 1. the `/add/` regex match and 2. the `p`, print command and *that* is why the `{...}` brace block is needed?

Comment: @user4668401 - yes, there are two commands but the first one isn't your `/add`, it's actually `{` and that allows you to nest an address inside another one. Answer edited.

Comment: I want to mention that multiple addresses *are* possible in `vi` (or `ex`), and they look quite similar to `sed` addresses.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `sed -n -e '195,210s/add/&/p'` but that's more or less just silly.  :)

Comment: This excellent answer shows the weakness of SE.  Such an erudite and well expressed answer has garnered 7 (now 8 since I of course upvoted) votes.  Other, often inaccurate answers get hundreds more because of the topic.  Anyway, excellent answer, which has led me into some more sed research.

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation for `sed` the curly braces are used to group commands together. So

```
sed -n '195,210{/add/p}' <file>
```

Is first treated as an address range `195,210` with a block command. The block command then consists of the address specification `/add/` with the command print `p`

Answer (score 0):

The sed syntax  goes like

address/command.

So 195,210 is the first address you match, but then you want to execute a new command within that range, namely match "add", then print. Therefore you need to group this extra command using the curly braces.